# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'temp'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, training-data, arima

```
Weekly_Sales=df.temp

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In\[19\], line 1
\----\> 1 Weekly_Sales=df.temp

File \~\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\core\\generic.py:5902, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
5895 if (
5896     name not in self.\_internal_names_set
5897     and name not in self.\_metadata
5898     and name not in self.\_accessors
5899     and self.\_info_axis.\_can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
5900 ):
5901     return self\[name\]
\-\> 5902 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'temp'
```

I was trying to find the training and testing data Arima model Sales Forecasting

Comment: What does `print(df.columns)` show you?